# Redux Socket.io Middleware Dispatches one action more than once

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, socket.io, react-redux

I have a custom redux action in the format below that is supposed to listen to a set of events emitted by a socket.io server and dispatch actions with payload based on the events fired. Problem is when an event is emitted from the server once, the middleware seems to be firing more than 4 or five times in some cases causing the app to crash. What could be the issue. 
The code for the middleware is as below:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { WORKOUT_EVENTS } from "./constants";

export default socketIOReduxMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    const socket  = io("http://192.168.1.16:3001", { reconnect: true, pingTimeout: 10000, pingInterval: 3000, transports: ["websocket", "polling"] });

    WORKOUT_EVENTS.forEach(event => {
        socket.on(event, payload => {
            store.dispatch({ type: event, payload });
        }); 
    });
    next(action);
};
```

The constants file has the following code:

```
export const WORKOUT_EVENTS = [
"start workout",
"wait trigger",
"phase countdown",
"phase break",
"exercise countdown",
"exercise",
"exercise explanation",
"round countdown",
"main phase exercises",
"station change",
"end workouts"
];
```

That's the full middleware code.

Comment: Aren't you adding multiple listeners here?

Comment: No I have used the same connection settings to test using `http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool` and when the socket server dispatches action it is only logged once instead of the many time in the react-native app

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, but you have `socket.on` inside a loop, so it's being registered more than once.

Comment: Ok. How would you re-write this?

Comment: I'd need to see more code. I'd try removing the `forEach()` code first of all and putting it somewhere else.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the constants file code. The is then just passed to the store like any other middleware

Answer (score 3):

Found out that the `store => next => {}` block is called once when setting up but the `action => {}` block is called every time an action is dispatched. The working code then becomes

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import WORKOUT_EVENTS from './constants';

const socketIOReduxMiddleware = store => next => {
    const socket = io("192.168.1.8:8089", {  pingInterval: 3000, pingTimeout: 10000,transports: ["websocket", "polling"]
      });

    WORKOUT_EVENTS.forEach(event => {
        socket.on(event, payload => {
            store.dispatch({ type: event, payload});
        });
    });

    return action => {
        next(action);
    }
}

export default socketIOReduxMiddleware;
```